# sed remove all single line c++ comments, asterisk operator not working

Tags: c++, regex, bash, shell, sed

I am using sed commands directly in bash script
I am trying to remove all single line c++ comments
I have tried this :

`sed "s/\/\/*//" sample-input.cpp > out.cpp`

but the above code is not having any difference than the following code on the result :

`sed "s/\/\//YAHOO/" sample-input.cpp > out.cpp`

i.e. the two front slashes in my code are going away but the * is having no effect. Help me with this

Comment: Job security in the making.

Comment: Change `*` to `.*`, or something more specific.

Comment: You're matching zero or more forward-slashes.

Comment: @jordanm thank you since i am a beginner the .* is definately working but there is a blank line over there that is remaining. i am also not aware of the difference b/w * and .*

Comment: * stands for zero or more occurences of the previous pattern, when there is no pattern there is nothing to match to

Comment: @Vinny sorry but as far as i am taught * represents any characters and any length of them so i do not know what you are telling me

Comment: [The GNU sed manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html).

Comment: @J.Dow that's not correct for regex patterns. `.` means any character.

Comment: @J.Dow If you're thinking of the shell's expansion of filenames, that's not the same thing.

Comment: @molbdnilo aren't they both regular expressions?

Comment: @J.Dow There are many different variations of regular expressions.

Comment: Be care that continuation line would broke your script `// comment on 2 lines \\`

Answer (score 0):

`*` stands for zero or more occurences of the previous pattern, when there is no pattern there is nothing to match to. You need to change this to something with a pattern, `.*` for example.

From GNU manual:

> *
>   Matches a sequence of zero or more instances of matches for the preceding regular expression, which must be an ordinary character, a special character preceded by \, a ., a grouped regexp (see below), or a bracket expression. As a GNU extension, a postfixed regular expression can also be followed by *; for example, a** is equivalent to a*.

So your line should be `sed "s/\/\/.*//" sample-input.cpp > out.cpp`
This will match `//` and anything that comes after.

To remove empty lines use: `sed -e '/^$/d' text`

`^` - line starts with

`$` - line ends with

Because there is nothing in between, it will match empty lines. `/d` option for sed is to delete.

If you want to remove just one new line after the comment, then you can use this combination:

`sed 's/\/\/.*/''/' text | cat -s`

and output it to a file. The `-s` option to `cat` squeezes consecutive blank lines into one. So every double new line would be merged into one.

Comment: `sed -i "s/^$/d/" out.cpp` i added that to by bash script but there is a `d` over there now. i am only introduced to the substitute command so can you help me using that?

Comment: I fixed that, it shouldn't be with `s/` at the beginning as this stands for substitute

Comment: What i want to confirm over here is that is there any way to achieve that using only the substitute commands?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Substitue means put something instead of something. what you want is to remove blank line, so you need to use \d

Comment: this is also removing non commented lines which are intentionally left blank

Comment: I've added another solution, which does what you probably need

Answer (score 0):

I guess you intented the following search "//". 
This should do it (not tested yet)

#### remove single line comments

case 1)

```
abc(); // oho
->
abc();
```

case 2)

```
   // oho
->

(empty line or removed line)
```

#### Solutions

```
sed "s/[ \t]*\/\/.*$//" sample-input.cpp > out.cpp

s/<pattern>//    substitue pattern by nothing     
[ \t]*           any tab or space 
\/\/             quoted //
.*               any chars
$                to end of line
```

to remove empty lines you can pipe into next sed

```
sed "s/[ \t]*\/\/.*$//" sample-input.cpp | sed "/^$/d" > out.cpp
```

However, the second sed will remove ANY empty line, not only such where had have comments

The save empty uncommented lines you may use this

```
sed "s/\/\/.*$/\/\//" sample-input.cpp | 
sed "/^[ \t]*\/\/$/d" |
sed "[ \t]*\/\/$" > out.cpp 

first sed normalize all single line comments
second sed removes empty lines which hold comments
third line remove append single line comments
```

if you only want to remove line of case 2, do

```
sed "/^[ \t]*\/\/.*$/d" sample-input.cpp > out.cpp 

/<pattern>/d    delete all line where pattern matches
```

When working with sed or similar tools your are always in danger not to catch all cases. For a perfect result you need a c++ parser.

One case where the sed above will fail is:

```
/*
 * asdahsdjhj // "single line comment" in multiline comment
 * will also removed
 */
```

However, the most people accept this weaknesses rather to have no solution

Comment: additional blank lines remaining

Comment: you can pipe into an other sed removing empty line. However, this will remove ANY empty line, not only such where had have comments.